# Multiprocessing com funções em loop infinito python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

Pessoal estou fazendo uma interface gráfica com o Gtk em python, e tenho um script serial que fica enviando e recebendo dados de um sistema microcontrolado. O script do serial fica em um loop infinito (while True:), já a interface entra em Gtk.main() e fica trancada ali dentro.
Preciso que os dois sejam abertos e executados juntos, já tentei o multiprocessing mas um código só abre quando o outro é encerrado. Por isso preciso saber como posso fazer isso, se há um outro módulo especifico.

## !/usr/bin/python3

import gi
import multiprocessing
import os
import subprocess
import threading
import Modulo_Serial

from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from subprocess import call
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
from datetime import datetime

class Aplicativo(object):

```
def __init__(self):

    #VALORES INICIAS DE VARIÁVEIS
    self.flag_tela_inicial   = 0
    self.flag_tela_principal = 1
    self.flag_tela_config01  = 1
    self.flag_tela_config02  = 1
    self.flag_tela_teste01   = 1

    self.flag_leitura_arquivo = 0




    self.timer_inicial       = 0
    self.timer_tela_config01 = 0
    self.timer_tela_config02 = 0


    self.timer_tela_teste01 = 0
    self.timer_tela_teste02 = 0
    self.timer_tela_teste03 = 0
    self.timer_tela_teste04 = 0
    self.flag_volume_init   = 0

    self.valor_teclado      = 0
    self.contador_teclado   = 0
    self.contador_teclado2  = 0
    self.pressao_set_valor  = 0
    self.tempo_set_valor    = 0


#DEFINICOES DE ABERTURA DAS TELAS

def tela_teclado01(self, flag_funcao):

    if (flag_funcao == 0):

        tela_teclado01_builder = Gtk.Builder()
        tela_teclado01_builder.add_from_file("tela_teclado01.glade")

        self.janela = tela_teclado01_builder.get_object("janela")
        self.janela.show()

    else:
        pass

def tela_inicializacao(self, flag_funcao):

    if(flag_funcao == 0):

        tela_inicial_builder = Gtk.Builder()
        tela_inicial_builder.add_from_file("tela_inicial.glade")

        self.qwr_txt          = tela_inicial_builder.get_object("wrs_txt")
        self.tourniquet_txt   = tela_inicial_builder.get_object("logo_txt")
        self.bemvindo_txt     = tela_inicial_builder.get_object("bemvindo_txt")
        self.janela_inicial   = tela_inicial_builder.get_object("janela")
        self.texto_inicial    = tela_inicial_builder.get_object("texto_inicial_txt")


        try:


            self.arquivo_config = open("data/config.dat", "r")

            self.linha01 = self.arquivo_config.readline()
            self.arquivo_config.close()

            try:
                self.linha01 = int(self.linha01)
            except:
                self.linha01 = 1

            self.num_idioma = self.linha01


        except:
            print("*Erro ao abri arquivo config.dat tela inicial")








        #COLOCANDO HORA E DATA ATUAL NAS CONFIGURAÇÕES DE HORA
        data_hora = datetime.now()
        self.data_config_txt.set_text(str(data_hora.day) + "/" + str(data_hora.month) + "/" + str(data_hora.year) )
        self.hora_config_txt.set_text(str(data_hora.hour)+ ":"+ str(data_hora.minute))


        #CONECTANDO OS SINAIS DO XML
        tela_configuracao01_builder.connect_signals({  "avancar01_bt_clicked"    : self.bt_avancar_confing01,
                                                       "restautar_bt_clicked"    : self.botao_restaura_default,
                                                       "idioma_cb_changed"       : self.selecao_idioma,
                                                       "tempo_cb_changed"        : self.selecao_tempo,
                                                       "volume_bt_clicked"       : self.botao_volume_init,
                                                       "pressao_set_bt_clicked"  : self.botao_set_pressao,
                                                       "tempo_set_bt_clicked"    : self.botao_set_tempo,
                                                       "tecla_1_clicked"         : self.botao_tecla_1,
                                                       "tecla_2_clicked"         : self.botao_tecla_2,
                                                       "tecla_3_clicked"         : self.botao_tecla_3,
                                                       "tecla_4_clicked"         : self.botao_tecla_4,
                                                       "tecla_5_clicked"         : self.botao_tecla_5,
                                                       "tecla_6_clicked"         : self.botao_tecla_6,
                                                       "tecla_7_clicked"         : self.botao_tecla_7,
                                                       "tecla_8_clicked"         : self.botao_tecla_8,
                                                       "tecla_9_clicked"         : self.botao_tecla_9,
                                                       "tecla_0_clicked"         : self.botao_tecla_0,
                                                       "tecla_backs_clicked"     : self.botao_tecla_backs,
                                                       "tecla_ok_clicked"        : self.botao_teclaok,
                                                       "tecla_21_clicked"        : self.botao_tecla21,
                                                       "tecla_22_clicked"        : self.botao_tecla22,
                                                       "tecla_23_clicked"        : self.botao_tecla23,
                                                       "tecla_24_clicked"        : self.botao_tecla24,
                                                       "tecla_25_clicked"        : self.botao_tecla25,
                                                       "tecla_26_clicked"        : self.botao_tecla26,
                                                       "tecla_27_clicked"        : self.botao_tecla27,
                                                       "tecla_28_clicked"        : self.botao_tecla28,
                                                       "tecla_29_clicked"        : self.botao_tecla29,
                                                       "tecla_20_clicked"        : self.botao_tecla20,
                                                       "tecla_backs2_clicked"    : self.botao_teclabacks2,
                                                       "tecla_ok2_clicked"       : self.botao_teclaok2
                                               })

        self.tempo_config_txt.set_text(str(self.tempo_set_valor))
        self.pressao_set_config_txt.set_text(str(self.pressao_set_valor))

        #FAZ LEITURA DO ARQUIVO DE CONFIGURAÇOES
        if(self.flag_leitura_arquivo == 0 or flag_funcao == 10):

            self.flag_leitura_arquivo = 1

            try:


                self.arquivo_config = open("data/config.dat", "r")

                self.linha01 = self.arquivo_config.readline()
                self.linha02 = self.arquivo_config.readline()

                self.arquivo_config.close()

                try:
                    self.linha01 = int(self.linha01)
                except:
                    self.linha01 = 1

                try:
                    self.linha02 = int(self.linha02)
                except:
                    self.linha02 = 0





            except:
                print("*Erro ao ler arquivo config.dat")



            try:


                self.num_idioma = self.linha01
                self.flag_volume_init = self.linha02
                self.pressao_set_config_txt.set_text(str(self.linha03))
                self.tempo_config_txt.set_text(str(self.linha04))
                self.num_tempo = self.linha05
                self.idioma_combobox.set_active((self.num_idioma-1))
                self.tempo_combobox.set_active((self.num_tempo- 1  ))
                self.tela_configuracao01(4, 1, self.flag_volume_init)

            except:
                print("*Erro nas conversões")

        #ABRINDO A JANELA DE CONFIGURAÇÃO 01
        self.janela_config01 = tela_configuracao01_builder.get_object("janela")
        self.janela_config01.show()


    # FLAG_FUNCAO 1 É PARA FECHAR A TELA E SALVAR AS CONFIGURAÇÕES SETADAS PELO USUÁRIO
    elif(flag_funcao == 1):

        #ABRE O ARQUIVO DE CONFIGURAÇÕES PARA SALVAR CONFIGURAÇÕES

        try:

            #FAZ LEITURA DAS POSIÇÕES DOS COMOBOX PARA ARMAZENAR

            self.num_idioma = int(self.idioma_combobox.get_active_id())
            self.num_tempo  = int(self.tempo_combobox.get_active_id())

            #ABRE ARQUIVO E SALVA INFORMAÇÕES
            self.arquivo_config = open("data/config.dat", "w")

            self.arquivo_config.write(str(self.num_idioma) + "\n")
            self.arquivo_config.write(str(flag_volume) + "\n")
            self.arquivo_config.write(str(self.pressao_set_config_txt.get_text()) + "\n")
            self.arquivo_config.write(str(self.tempo_config_txt.get_text())+ "\n")
            self.arquivo_config.write(str(self.num_tempo) + "\n")
            self.arquivo_config.close()
        except:
            print("*Erro ao abrir arquivo config.dat")


        #FECHA A JANELA DE CONFIGURAÇÃO
        self.janela_config01.close()


    # FLAG_FUNCAO 2 É QUANDO O COMBOBOX DE IDOMA É SELECIONADO, VERIFICA O IDIOMA E TRADUZ TELA
    elif(flag_funcao == 2):

        #FAZ LEITURA DA POSIÇÃO DO COMOBOBOX DE IDIOMA
        self.num_idioma = int(self.idioma_combobox.get_active_id())



    #FLAG FUNCAO 3 É QUANDO O COMBOBOX DA CONTAGEM DO TEMPO É SELECIONADO, FAZ LEITURA E SALVA
    elif (flag_funcao == 3):

        self.num_tempo = int(self.tempo_combobox.get_active_id())

    #FLAG FUNCAO 4  NÃO FAZ NADA
    elif(flag_funcao == 4):
        pass

    elif(flag_funcao == 5):

        self.volume_tit_txt.set_visible(0)

        self.imagem_fundo_config1.set_from_file("img_fundo_janela_principal2.png")

    elif (flag_funcao == 6):


        self.contador_teclado = self.contador_teclado + 1

        if(self.contador_teclado == 1 and self.valor_teclado!=11):

            self.pressao_set_valor = self.valor_teclado

        elif(self.contador_teclado == 2 and self.valor_teclado!=11):

            self.pressao_set_valor = (self.pressao_set_valor * 10)
            self.pressao_set_valor = self.pressao_set_valor+ (self.valor_teclado)

        elif(self.contador_teclado == 3 and self.valor_teclado!=11):

            self.pressao_set_valor = self.pressao_set_valor * 10
            self.pressao_set_valor = self.pressao_set_valor + (self.valor_teclado)

            self.contador_teclado = 0

        if(self.valor_teclado == 11):
            self.contador_teclado = 0
            self.valor_teclado = 0
            self.pressao_set_valor = 0






        self.imagem_fundo_config1.set_from_file("img_fundo_janela_principal.png")

    elif (flag_funcao == 8):



        self.titulo_txt.set_visible(0)


        self.imagem_fundo_config1.set_from_file("img_fundo_janela_principal3.png")

    elif (flag_funcao == 9):

        self.contador_teclado2 = self.contador_teclado2 + 1

        if(self.contador_teclado2 == 1 and self.valor_teclado!=11):

            self.tempo_set_valor = self.valor_teclado

        elif(self.contador_teclado2 == 2 and self.valor_teclado!=11):

            self.tempo_set_valor = (self.tempo_set_valor * 10)
            self.tempo_set_valor = self.tempo_set_valor+ (self.valor_teclado)

        elif(self.contador_teclado2 == 3 and self.valor_teclado!=11):

            self.tempo_set_valor = self.tempo_set_valor * 10
            self.tempo_set_valor = self.tempo_set_valor + (self.valor_teclado)

            self.contador_teclado2 = 0

        if(self.valor_teclado==11):
            self.contador_teclado = 0
            self.valor_teclado = 0
            self.tempo_set_valor = 0

        self.tempo_config_txt.set_text(str(self.tempo_set_valor))


    elif (flag_funcao == 11):








#BOTÕES E EVENTOS DA TELA DE CONFIGURAÇÃO 01

def desligaaa(self,widget):
    Gtk.main_quit()

def botao_set_pressao(self, widget):
    self.tela_configuracao01(5,0,0)


def botao_set_tempo(self, widget):
    self.tela_configuracao01(8, 0, 0)





def botao_tecla_0(self, widget):
    self.valor_teclado = 0
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)



def botao_tecla_1(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 1
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)


def botao_tecla_2(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 2
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla_3(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 3
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla_4(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 4
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla_5(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 5
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla_6(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 6
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla_7(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 7
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla_8(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 8
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla_9(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 9
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla_backs(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 11
    self.tela_configuracao01(6, 0, 0)

def botao_teclaok (self, widget):


    if (self.pressao_set_valor > self.pressao_max):
        self.pressao_set_valor = self.pressao_max



    elif (self.pressao_set_valor < self.pressao_min):
        self.pressao_set_valor = self.pressao_min


    self.pressao_set_config_txt.set_text(str(self.pressao_set_valor))

    self.tela_configuracao01(7,0,0)

def botao_tecla20(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 0
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla21(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 1
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla22(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 2
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla23(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 3
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla24(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 4
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla25(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 5
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla26(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 6
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla27(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 7
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla28(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 8
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_tecla29(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 9
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_teclabacks2(self, widget):

    self.valor_teclado = 11
    self.tela_configuracao01(9, 0, 0)

def botao_teclaok2(self, widget):

    if (self.tempo_set_valor > self.tempo_max):
        self.tempo_set_valor = self.tempo_max



    elif (self.tempo_set_valor < self.tempo_min):
        self.tempo_set_valor = self.tempo_min

    self.tempo_config_txt.set_text(str(self.tempo_set_valor))

    self.tela_configuracao01(11, 0, 0)




########### TELA DE CONFIGURAÇÃO 02 ###########
def tela_configuracao02(self,flag):

    if(flag == 0):

        tela_config01_builder = Gtk.Builder()
        tela_config01_builder.add_from_file("tela_inicial.glade")

        #PEGANDO OBJETOS TXT
        self.qwr_txt        = tela_config01_builder.get_object("qwe_txt")
        self.tourniquet_txt = tela_config01_builder.get_object("none_txt")
        self.texto_inicial  = tela_config01_buildeitr.get_object("texto_inicial_txt")
        self.bemvindo_txt   = tela_config01_builder.get_object("bemvindo_txt")

        self.janela_config01 = tela_config01_builder.get_object("janela")

        self.bemvindo_txt.set_text(" ")



def tela_teste01(self,flag):

    if(flag == 0 or flag == 10):

        tela_teste01_builder = Gtk.Builder()
        tela_teste01_builder.add_from_file("tela_teste01.glade")
        tela_teste01_builder.connect_signals({"ok01_bt_clicked" : self.botao_ok_teste02})

        self.texto01_txt = tela_teste01_builder.get_object("texto01_txt")
        self.erro_txt = tela_teste01_builder.get_object("erro_txt")
        self.janela_teste01 = tela_teste01_builder.get_object("janela")

        if (self.num_idioma == 1):
            self.texto01_txt.set_text("Performing self test")
            self.erro_txt.set_text("PULL THE SLEEVE, OK TO CONTINUE")

            # 2 PORTUGUÊS
        elif (self.num_idioma == 2):
            self.texto01_txt.set_text("Realizando teste automático")
            self.erro_txt.set_text("TIRE O MANGUITO, OK PARA CONTINUAR")

            # ESPANHOL
        elif (self.num_idioma == 3):
            pass

        self.janela_teste01.show()

    else:
        self.janela_teste01.close()

def botao_ok_teste02(self, widget):

        self.flag_tela_teste01 = 1
        self.tela_teste01(self.flag_tela_teste01)
        self.flag_tela_teste02 = 0
        self.tela_teste02(self.flag_tela_teste02)


def tela_teste02(self,flag):

    if(flag == 0):

        tela_teste02_builder = Gtk.Builder()
        tela_teste02_builder.add_from_file("tela_teste02.glade")
        tela_teste02_builder.connect_signals({"bt_avancar_clicked" : self.botao_avancar_teste02})
        self.texto01_txt = tela_teste02_builder.get_object("texto01_txt")
        self.erro_txt = tela_teste02_builder.get_object("erro_txt")
        self.check_bt_txt = tela_teste02_builder.get_object("check_button_txt")
        self.bt_avancar_txt = tela_teste02_builder.get_object("bt_avancar")
        self.janela_teste02 = tela_teste02_builder.get_object("janela")

        if (self.num_idioma == 1):
            self.texto01_txt.set_text("Performing self test")
            self.erro_txt.set_text("INFLATED SLEEVE :")
            self.check_bt_txt.set_text("Depressurise")
            self.bt_avancar_txt.set_label("Next")

            # 2 PORTUGUÊS
        elif (self.num_idioma == 2):
            self.texto01_txt.set_text("Realizando teste automático")
            self.erro_txt.set_text("MANGUITO INFLADO :")
            self.check_bt_txt.set_text("Depressurizar")
            self.bt_avancar_txt.set_label("Avançar")
            # ESPANHOL
        elif (self.num_idioma == 3):
            pass


        self.janela_teste02.show()

    else:
        self.janela_teste02.close()

def tela_principal(self,flag):

    if(flag == 0 ):

        # IMPORTANDO OBJETOS
        tela_principal_builder = Gtk.Builder()
        tela_principal_builder.add_from_file("tela_principal.glade")
        self.janela_principal = tela_principal_builder.get_object("janela")


        self.pressao01_txt      = tela_principal_builder.get_object("pressao01_txt")
        self.pressao02_txt      = tela_principal_builder.get_object("pressao02_txt")
        self.tempo01_txt        = tela_principal_builder.get_object("tempo01_txt")
        self.tempo02_txt        = tela_principal_builder.get_object("tempo02_txt")
        self.pressao01_tit_txt  = tela_principal_builder.get_object("pressao01_tit_txt")
        self.pressao02_tit_txt  = tela_principal_builder.get_object("pressao02_tit_txt")
        self.desinfla1_bt2_txt  = tela_principal_builder.get_object("desinfla1_bt2_txt")
        self.desinfla1_bt1_txt  = tela_principal_builder.get_object("desinfla1_bt1_txt")
        self.infla1_bt1_txt     = tela_principal_builder.get_object("infla1_bt1_txt")
        self.desinfla2_bt2_txt  = tela_principal_builder.get_object("desinfla2_bt2_txt")
        self.desinfla2_bt1_txt  = tela_principal_builder.get_object("desinfla2_bt1_txt")
        self.infla1_bt2_txt     = tela_principal_builder.get_object("infla2_bt1_txt")

        self.volume_icon_img    = tela_principal_builder.get_object("volume_icon_img")
        self.energia_icon_img   = tela_principal_builder.get_object("energia_icon_img")
        self.bateria_icon_img   = tela_principal_builder.get_object("bateria_icon_img")

        self.pressao01_barra    = tela_principal_builder.get_object("valor_barra_pressao01")
        self.pressao02_barra    = tela_principal_builder.get_object("valor_barra_pressao02")
        self.tempo01_barra      = tela_principal_builder.get_object("valor_barra_tempo01")
        self.tempo02_barra      = tela_principal_builder.get_object("valor_barra_tempo02")

        self.inflar01_bt01      = tela_principal_builder.get_object("infla1_bt1")
        self.desinfla01_bt01    = tela_principal_builder.get_object("desinfla1_bt1")
        self.desinfla01_bt02    = tela_principal_builder.get_object("desinfla1_bt2")

        self.inflar02_bt01 = tela_principal_builder.get_object("infla2_bt1")
        self.desinfla02_bt01 = tela_principal_builder.get_object("desinfla2_bt1")
        self.desinfla02_bt02 = tela_principal_builder.get_object("desinfla2_bt2")

        # CONECTANDO OS SINAIS DA TELA PRINCIPAL
        tela_principal_builder.connect_signals({"pressao1_bt_mais_clicked"  : self.botao_mais_pressao01,
                                            "pressao1_bt_menos_clicked"     : self.botao_menos_pressao01,
                                            "tempo1_bt_mais_clicked"        : self.botao_mais_tempo01,
                                            "tempo1_bt_menos_clicked"       : self.botao_menos_tempo01,
                                            "pressao2_bt_mais_clicked"      : self.botao_mais_pressao02,
                                            "pressao2_bt_menos_clicked"     : self.botao_menos_pressao02,
                                            "tempo2_bt_mais_clicked"        : self.botao_mais_tempo02,
                                            "tempo2_bt_menos_clicked"       : self.botao_menos_tempo02,
                                            "volume_bt_clicked"             : self.botao_volume,
                                            "infla1_bt1_clicked"            : self.botao_inflar01,
                                            "pressao01_barra_value_changed" : self.barra_pressao01,
                                            "pressao02_barra_value_changed" : self.barra_pressao02,
                                            "tempo01_barra_value_changed"   : self.barra_tempo01,
                                            "tempo02_barra_value_changed"   : self.barra_tempo02,
                                            "energia_icon_img_destroy"      : self.fechar_programa,
                                            "bt_config_clicked"             : self.botao_configuracao,
                                            "bt_teste_clicked"              : self.botao_realiza_teste,
                                            "desinfla1_bt1_clicked"         : self.botao1_desinfla1,
                                            "desinfla1_bt2_clicked"         : self.botao2_desinfla1,
                                            "desinfla2_bt1_clicked"         : self.botao1_desinfla2,
                                            "desinfla2_bt2_clicked"         : self.botao2_desinfla2,
                                            "infla2_bt1_clicked"            : self.botao1_infla2,

                                            })

        self.janela_principal.show()

        # VARIAVEIS DA CLASSE
        self.pressao01_set = 0
        self.pressao02_set = 0
        self.tempo01_set = 0
        self.tempo02_set = 0
        self.volume_cont = 3

        # LENDO ARQUIVOS PARA VALORES INICIAIS
        try:
            self.Arquivo = open("data/pressao01_set.dat", "r")
            self.pressao01_set = int(self.Arquivo.readline())
            self.Arquivo.close()

        except:
            self.pressao01_set = 300

        try:
            self.Arquivo = open("data/pressao02_set.dat", "r")
            self.pressao02_set = int(self.Arquivo.readline())
            self.Arquivo.close()

        except:
            self.pressao02_set = 300

        try:
            self.Arquivo = open("data/tempo01_set.dat", "r")
            self.tempo01_set = int(self.Arquivo.readline())
            self.Arquivo.close()

        except:
            self.tempo01_set = 60

        try:
            self.Arquivo = open("data/tempo02_set.dat", "r")
            self.tempo02_set = int(self.Arquivo.readline())
            self.Arquivo.close()

        except:
            self.tempo02_set = 60

        # MUDANDO A POSIÇÃO DAS BARRAS DE ACORDO COM O VALOR SETADO

        self.pressao01_barra.set_value(self.pressao01_set)
        self.pressao02_barra.set_value(self.pressao02_set)
        self.tempo01_barra.set_value(self.tempo01_set)
        self.tempo02_barra.set_value(self.tempo02_set)

        # ESCREVENDO NA TELA OS VALORES INICIAS LIDOS NOS ARQUIVOS
        self.pressao01_txt.set_text(str(self.pressao01_set))
        self.pressao02_txt.set_text(str(self.pressao02_set))
        self.tempo01_txt.set_text(str(self.tempo01_set))
        self.tempo02_txt.set_text(str(self.tempo02_set))
    else:
        self.janela_principal.close()

def botao_configuracao(self, widget):
    self.tela_principal(1)
    self.flag_tela_config01 = 10
    self.tela_configuracao01(self.flag_tela_config01,0,0)

def botao_realiza_teste(self,widget):

    self.timer_tela_teste03 = 0
    self.timer_tela_teste04 = 0
    self.flag_tela_teste01 = 0
    self.tela_teste01(self.flag_tela_teste01)

    self.flag_tela_principal = 1
    self.tela_principal(self.flag_tela_principal)


def fechar_programa(self, widget):

    Gtk.main_quit()

    #EVENTO DOS BOTÕES DA TELA PRINCIPAL




    # Initialize Timer
def timer_tela_inicio(self):
    #  this takes 2 args: (how often to update in millisec, the method to run)
    GObject.timeout_add(1000, self.func_tela_inicio)

def teste(self):
    #  this takes 2 args: (how often to update in millisec, the method to run)
    GObject.timeout_add(1000, self.daprint)
def daprint(self):
    self.teste()
    print("timerzeira")
```

def InitProg():
    Gtk.main()

def InitCom():
    Teste = Modulo_Serial.Comunicacao()
    Teste.SerialInit("/dev/ttyUSB1",115200,1,1,)

```
vetor = [0, 20, 47, 10, 100, 100, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 10, 11, 23]
dadosrec = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# print(vetor)
Teste.PreparaBufferTx(vetor)
# print(vetor)
Teste.EscritaSerial(vetor)
# print(dadosrec)
Teste.Leitura_Serial(dadosrec)
# print(dadosrec)
```

App = Aplicativo()

App.timer_tela_inicio()
App.teste()

App.tela_inicializacao(App.flag_tela_inicial)

## Init=  multiprocessing.Process(name = "InitProg",target=InitProg)

## Init2=  multiprocessing.Process(name = "InitProg",target=InitCom)

## Init.run()

## Init2.run()

## DadosRx,DadosTx = Pipe()

t = threading.Thread(target=InitCom)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=InitProg)
t.start()
t2.start()
t.join()
t2.join()

Comment: Então você poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar este código que escreveu? Leia também sobre *threads*, talvez satisfaça seu problema.

Comment: multiprocessing é melhor aí - por que threads vão conflitar como GTK+ - elas vão complicar, não facilitar.

Mas..tudo isso é especulação inútil sem vermos como está o código.

Comment: Filipe: se você não editar a pergunta e colocar trechos do código que permitam que a getne dê sugestões de como você pode fazer, não vai ter resposta e a pergunta vai ser fechada. Do jeito que está, o único jeito de te responder seria escrever seu sistema inteiro como "exemplo".

Comment: jsbueno coloquei uma versão limitada do código, mas só uso telas e eventos de botões e um timer. Dá uma olhada para ver se pode ajudar!

Comment: Usando as threads consegui executar os dois .py juntos. Mas agora fiquei na dúvida quanto ao que o jsbueno comentou. Eu sou programador C para microcontroladores, então entrei a pouco no python. Preciso saber o que é mais confiável.

Comment: Se eu colocar algum while dentro do código serial, as telas do Gtk não vão abrir, até que seja encerrado o loop. Da mesma forma ao entrar no GTK.main() nada mais é executado. Até tentei descobrir e entender o que faz o Gtk.main mas não consegui.

Comment: @Filipesantos leia sobre [mcve]. Seu código excede os 30.000 caracteres da pergunta e isso já é um belo indicativo que será impossível analisar o código completo.

Comment: Sim, mas só removi a criação de algumas telas e eventos de botões.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No construtor da janela do seu programa você deve iniciar uma nova thread com a classe do microcontrolador (que é a classe que contém o loop infinito que comunica com o microcontrolador).

Para fazer a comunicação entre a tela e  classe do microcontrolador você deve utilizar um [design pattern chamado observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Ele é muito fácil de ser implementado no Python porque você não precisa criar contratos entre as classes.

Como a sua classe do microcontrolador tem um loop infinito, você deve ter uma fila de mensagens que será processada em cada iteração do loop. A tela vai inserir mensagens na fila (através do observer pattern) e a fila será processada no loop. Essa técnica é muito comum em ambientes multiprocessados.

O Python possui [uma fila thread-safe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) então você pode usar ela e não precisa se preocupar com problemas de racing conditions.

Comment: Gabriel obrigado pela resposta. Tenho pouco conhecimento em python, então não entendi muito a ideia que você falou, mas vou pesquisar para tentar entender! Obrigado por me mostrar caminhos!

Comment: Trabalhar em ambientes multiprocessados é uma tarefa meio complicada porque o programa se comporta de maneira pouco intuitiva, então é normal ficar confuso até adquirir experiência. Se você sente que minha resposta supriu sua dúvida, não esqueça de marcá-la como correta. Boa sorte no seu projeto!